# XCode 4 - create AppController standard?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, design-patterns

I'm using XCode 4, and note that when setting up a new Cocoa Application project, you get an AppDelegate.m and .h file, as well as a .nib (.xib). Using alt-command-return, you get the 3-column editor layout, from which you can control-drag from controls to the AppDelegate.h file to create Outlets or Actions.

My question is, is it recommended to utilise these AppDelegate files to manage your interface controls ie. updating labels, acting on button presses etc. OR is it better to create an AppController class, add an object to the .xib and subclass it to AppController, modifying AppController to mange the controls? If this is the case, what are appropriate uses of AppDelegate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to say, it is just a matter of development style. What I do is use another class and change the AppDelegate to that class/view and use. Also I do not draw outlets and button on the default window. I make a view and add those as subviews to the mainWindow.

Comment: Thanks Anoop - I did gather there was an element of style to it.

Comment: Actually this is what I have learnt from my senior-he has got 10+ yrs experience in cocoa/objective-c.